# Django virtualenv deployment configuration

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I recently start to use virtualenvwrapper and created

```
mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
mkvirtualenv example.com
```

Virtualenvwarpper automatical create a virtualenv named example.com under ~/.virtualenv
so this is the central container for all virtualenvs.
After than I installed django and some other packages via pip
and my site is at

```
 /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
```

Do I have to put my site to
 ~/.virtualenv/example.com 
if not how could I use my example.com virtualenv with my site under /srv/www/example.com/public_html.
Could you show me  an apache mod_wsgi configuration for this deployment?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

It may not be sufficient to use just site.addsitedir() as it doesn't deal with certain ordering issues. You are better off using the configuration directive/option provided by mod_wsgi to add them. Otherwise, if the ordering becomes an issue you will need to add code into WSGI script that reorders sys.path as necessary.

Comment: This worked well for me, but not until I realized I do need both parts, even though I want to use my baseline virtualenv for my application.  So you must set "WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/pythonenv/BASELINE" in the global apache config, and then you must ALSO add the site.addsitedir command to the top of your .wsgi script, even if you're planning on using your baseline.   The docs reference the python libs with 2.5 but they are probably now 2.6 for you:  site.addsitedir('/usr/local/pythonenv/BASELINE/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

Comment: You should not need to do it in both places. Something else is wrong if you had to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In your WSGI script:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/home/username/.virtualenvs/example.com/lib/python2.5/site-packages')
```

(Adjust as appropriate for your Python version, etc.)

Comment: That's not enough. See Graham's answer.