# upgrading python in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, virtualenv

Currently I have a working site on Ubuntu 10.04, python 2.6.5, Django 1.3, virtualenv and mod_wsgi.  I also have nginx serving the static files, but I'm not sure that fits into this equation.

I set this up over a year ago and really only learned enough to get it going, so I don't remember the exact steps I took to get it going initially.

I have a need to start using python 2.7, but I'm not exactly sure the best way to go about that.  From what I've read, it looks like I need to re-install mod_wsgi specifically for 2.7.

I believe the steps to accomplish this are something like the following:

1. uninstall mod_wsgi.
2. insatll python 2.7 (I believe this can live alongside 2.6?)
3. re-install mod_wsgi specifically for python 2.7.
4. create a new virtualenv using 2.7 and re-install requirements.

I'm also looking at my django.wsgi file that I had setup that apache points to (in my project):

```
import os, sys
import site

wsgi_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
project_dir = os.path.dirname(wsgi_dir)
root_dir = os.path.join(project_dir, '..')

site.addsitedir(os.path.join(root_dir, 'env/lib/python2.6/site-packages'))
sys.path.append(project_dir)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And I don't see anywhere that I specifically call out the python binary to use, so I think I need to add something in there for that.

So my question is:
What are the steps I need to take to upgrade my setup to python 2.7?

Comment: If you flag my post for removal please offer some advice of how to improve or where to put it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is this a virtual machine or hardware? Can you just provision a new server with python 2.7?

Comment: What is your specific need for Python 2.7?

Comment: Probably a question better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

The following two links may be of some help:

1. [How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)
   especially the section "Using a virtualenv"
2. a similar question: [Django virtualenv deployment configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462102/django-virtualenv-deployment-configuration)

Comment: I already have the setup working with python 2.6, I'm just wondering what it takes to upgrade to python 2.7.  I suppose it's just delete everything and install from scratch?

Comment: Install python 2.7 into a virtualenv, and then follow the above links